# .net make dll for single aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, publish

I have a published project which is used by side company and which can not be updated now. The application got quite some changes which should not be published to this certain URL. Instead on one aspx page.

Question - how can I create DLL for one single aspx page inside big project so I will be able publish only it.

Thank you

Comment: you can create a project, with one page, publish it... but you need to put a link to that page fro old one right?

Comment: I dont need to have a link, but this aspx page should be under the main url of the site and be in the root

Comment: Thank you ArsenMkrt, it works. I added extra project, moved the file there, built, and copied to the server. and it works :) Thank you. Can be closed the question

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate all logic in a class library :

```
public class MyBusinessLogic
{
  public bool DoSomethingWithFormData(string val1, string val2)
  {
   //do your logic here...
  }
}
```

And create your Aspx page , in the code behind use :

```
  protected void YourButtonOnPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
          MyBusinessLogicm = new MyBusinessLogic();
          m.DoSomethingWithFormData(txt1.Text,txt2.Text);
  }
```

In this way you have to publish only a dll and an aspx page. 
Note that the code is not clean.. don't pass textbox data to business in this way but do some validation first.

Comment: So I have very big page with a lot of controls and the same with code behind. Will it work also? For now Im trying to run aspnet_compiler.exe with -fixednames to get separated dlls for all files. bt currently getting errors

Comment: But if still have in code behind YourButtonOnPage_Click than I need to have this code somewhere, in dll of project. but I can not update dll in project

Comment: If you're using a command line then try use Web Development Project for generate separeted dlls for all files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx. I misunderstood the question sorry.

Comment: I used aspnet_compiler.exe and got 
admin.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled

But when I placed it into bin I got message
This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!

Any ideas?